# Get mail from gmail using service account

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-client, service-accounts, google-python-api

I'm using google service account for access all mail from gmail account without UI interface but When I execute my code it giving me error

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels?alt=json returned
>   "Bad Request">

But when i check Quotas from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/quotas
there is showing all request that I did using my python code but it always return *Bad request* when I execute below code.

```
import httplib2
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


def get_credentials():
    scopes = ['https://mail.google.com/',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic']

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        'client_secret.json', scopes=scopes)
    return credentials

def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])
    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think your implementation is not applicable to service accounts because you're using your 'own account' which isn't what a service account is. Check the code sample here [gmail_service_account_api](https://gist.github.com/timrichardson/1154e29174926e462b7a) as reference.

Comment: but why google quotas showing uses graph of API when I call `execute()` method. It's also showing which API I called from this code in quotas.
Can you tell me how I can fetch my emails without UI? I have cron on server that will read my email from gmail. any Idea?

Comment: i dont use cron

Comment: Ok. NP, but any idea to fetch email without UI?

Answer (score 0):

Much has changed since this post was first written,

If anyone else is still looking for an answer. This is my initialization process for the Gmail API today.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

def main():   
    # Setup for the Gmail API
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Gmail API to fetch INBOX
    results = service.users().labels().list().execute()
```

A major difference is the use of access tokens along with credentials in my code.